# Detect Keys Combination C# Winform

Tags: winforms

How to detect ctrl + e + h combination in c# winform please help...

```
if (e.Control && (e.KeyCode == Keys.E && e.KeyCode == Keys.H))
            {
                this.buttonExpenseHeads.PerformClick();
            }
```

Comment: this method only works for one(more) special key(like ctrl shift etc) and one(only one) text key(like a, b, c etc).

Comment: do you know any other way to implement the desired feature ?

Comment: Look if you don't have to use the same combination you can use two modifier keys and one normal key like control, shift, and E put this contion in key down event and this check for control, shift and e to be pressed simoultaniously                                                          if ((Control.ModifierKeys & Keys.Shift) == Keys.Shift&&(Control.ModifierKeys & Keys.Control) == Keys.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.E) 
            {
                MessageBox.Show("sada");
            }

Answer (score 1):

Below sample code will help you to achieve your requirement.

Define global variable as below. It will track last key pressed. I.e. E.

```
Keys lstKeyPressed;
```

Use below code in KeyDown event.

```
if (Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.H && lstKeyPressed == Keys.E)
{
    this.buttonExpenseHeads.PerformClick(); //Raise button click as you mentioned.
}

lstKeyPressed = e.KeyCode;
```

Please note that above sample code will work only for key combination Ctrl + E + H, not for Ctrl + H + E.